# Is the tag name [m2m] expressive enough?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I was just notified that I had a pending edit which was removing the [m2m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2m) tag from one of my posts. After reading the tag wiki, I had to approve it.

I was thinking that the tag was about model-to-model transformations. But the current tag wiki is:

> A type of relationship between entities of types A and B which associates a list of entities of type B to an entity of type A and vice versa. Types A and B may be the same type

The tag wiki refers also to the other tag [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many). The name m2m itself could also mean machine-to-machine communication.

Is the name of the tag itself ok? Is there some information missing in the tag wiki? Should it be made a synonym of [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many)? Or should [m2m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2m) be deleted and questions of it be retagged with [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many)?

**EDIT:**
I just noticed [m2m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2m) and [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many) have equal tag wikis.

Comment: It should be a synonym.

Comment: I had to look into the question, to know what [m2m] is. So I'd think, it's not.

Comment: From a database/object modeling point of view, m2m was always many-to-many. I was surprised to know there can be another meaning

Comment: I'm in big data analytics; I opened the discussion to see which of the potential meanings was the intended one, as "we" know this to be ambiguous.  In fact, the "x2y" syntax is so fraught with problems that we've pretty much banned it from our implementation and test code as being uncommunicative.  For instance, you may find a method "iarray2vec", but never "i2v".

Comment: I thought "m2m" meant merchant-to-merchant (some business thing...this is totally wrong). If I Google "m2m" the only technological thing I see is "[machine to machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_to_machine)", and I looked through page 5 of the results, which is basically infinity.

Comment: The only "m2m" I was familiar with was a clothing store for gay men. Like @kratenko, I had to open this question to see what the OP was trying to refer to. I would upvote a good No answer.

Comment: That's a terrible tag name. Just terrible.

Comment: In embedded software, M2M is a well-known abbreviation for machine-to-machine communication, although IoT (Internet of Things) has been catching on lately.  Top Google hit for me was Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_to_machine

Comment: I thought m2m was for the gay craigslist crowd.

Comment: @RickBross You're thinking of m4m.

Comment: i would think of the band and only the band. never heard m2m used in any other context.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the tag to check for the various usages of [m2m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2m), and I did find a lot of them:

- Many 2 Many:

  - Mostly the [Django questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bm2m%5D+%5Bdjango%5D++is%3Aq&mixed=0), these need to be ideally tagged with the [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many) tag. Surprisingly, there is a [django-many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-many-to-many) synonymized to [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm). So we need to ask with the Django experts on how to deal with this.
  - There are some SQL questions about Many to Many relationships, which is a perfect fit for the [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many) tag.
- Machine 2 Machine: There are a lot of IOT and Hardware related questions, from which the tag can just be dropped. They can be tagged with [machine-to-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-to-machine), but there seems to be just around 5~10 questions which are already well described by the other tags. (These seem on-topic, from the cursory glance that I took).
- Eclipse M2M, which is now called Eclipse MMT, which probably needs a new tag [eclipse-mmt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-mmt).
- A few questions about Made2Manage ERP, which probably needs to be closed (as they were all off-topic)

My proposal would be to retag the 50 questions that are not related to Django Many to Many, and then (after discussions with the django users) either merge with [many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/many-to-many) or [tag-django-many-to-many]. I personally prefer the first, as it is better to have more unprefixed tags than prefixed tags. (Not to mention the fact that Django's Many to Many is the same concept as the SQL Many to Many)